# PHP shell_exec GIT escape

Tags: php, git, shell

How can I escape this problem:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/example && git pull http://a.smatanik@xxx.com:pass@xxx.sk/clients/example.git master 2>&1'));
```

Problem is that my name contain @ character. I'm trying exec pull request through PHP script.

Thanks

Comment: What's your OS platform? Win/Linux

Comment: Also, that URL definitely does not seem valid... especially the `:` symbol, that's reserved fort `PORT` reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up your username in Git if it contains special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698755/how-to-set-up-your-username-in-git-if-it-contains-special-characters)